# std::unordered_set<T>::insert(T&&): is argument moved if it exists

Tags: c++, c++11

This question is about the specification of several functions in the C++11 Standard Library, that take their arguments as rvalue references, but do not consume them in all cases. One example is 
`std::unordered_set<T>::insert(T&&)`.

It is pretty clear, that this method will use the move constructor of `T` to construct the element within the container, if it does not already exist. However, what happens if the element already exists in the container? I am pretty sure there is no reason the change the object in the case. However, I didn't find anything in the C++11 Standard supporting my claim.

Here is an example to show why this might be interesting. The following code reads lines from std::cin and remove the first occurrence of duplicate lines.

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> seen;
std::string line;
while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
    bool inserted = seen.insert(std::move(line)).second;
    if (!inserted) {
        /* Is it safe to use line here, i.e. can I assume that the
         * insert operation hasn't changed the string object, because 
         * the string already exists, so there is no need to consume it. */
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Apparently, this example works with GCC 4.7. But I am not sure, if it is correct according to the standard.

Comment: It would be inefficient to move when it is not required, but only the Standard matters. Good question!

Comment: `std::cout << line << '\n';` Note that the standard doesn't say that this will work. `line` will be left in a "valid state with an unspecified value." You should check `line.empty()` instead.

Comment: This all sounds like it would make a great defect report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this note in the standard (17.4.6.9):

> [ *Note*: If a program casts an lvalue to an xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by calling the function with the argument `move(x)`), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary. The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument was an lvalue. — end note ]

While it doesn't directly answer your question it does indicate that you've effectively "given" the argument to the library function as a temporary so I wouldn't rely on its value once you've called `insert`. As far as I can tell, a library implementation would be entitled to move from the parameter even if it subsequently determines that it isn't going to keep the value in the container.

Comment: There's more than just optimisation to this, though: `unique_ptr` guarantees that after a move the original pointer is null. Is this the case when you insert a unique pointer into a map?

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is important to be really explicit with the meaning of *move* regarding the guarantee that you point out. The *move* there is not *calling* `std::move( uptr )`, but the *move-construction* or *move-assignment*. That is, the cast to an *rvalue-reference* does not remove the pointer from the `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics given for `insert` on unordered associative containers in §23.2.5/Table 103 don't specify whether the the move constructor of the argument to `insert` is invoked if the insert fails, the wording only talks about whether the insertion happens:

> **`a_uniq.insert(t)`**
>
> Returns: `pair<iterator, bool>`
>
> Requires: If `t` is a non-const
>   rvalue expression, `T` shall be MoveInsertable into X; otherwise, `T`
>   shall be CopyInsertable into `X`.
>
> Effects: Inserts `t` if and only if
>   there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of
>   `t`. The bool component of the returned pair indicates whether the
>   insertion takes place, and the iterator component points to the
>   element with key equivalent to the key of `t`.

<s>However, the specification for `emplace` is clearer (also from Table 103), and you should be able to use it instead of `insert` to get the guarantees you want:</s>

> **`a_uniq.emplace(args)`**
>
> Returns: `pair<iterator, bool>`
>
> Requires: T shall be
>   EmplaceConstructible into `X` from args.
>
> Effects: Inserts a `T` object `t`
>   constructed with std::forward(args)... *if and only if there is
>   no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of `t`*. The
>   bool component of the returned pair is true if and only if the
>   insertion takes place, and the iterator component of the pair points
>   to the element with key equivalent to the key of `t`.

I interpret this to mean ((Inserts a `T` object `t` constructed ...) (if and only if there is no element in the container ...)), *i.e.* both the insertion and construction should only happen if there is no matching element already in the container. If no object is constructed , the `std::string` you pass in will never be passed to a move constructor, and therefore will still be valid after the failed `emplace` call.

gcc 4.7.0 doesn't seem to support `unordered_set::emplace`, but it is in the standard (§23.5.6.1)

As @NicolBolas pointed out in the comments, and despite the above, it's impossible to implement an `emplace` function that doesn't construct a `T` if a conflicting entry already exists.

So the only way to get the semantics you want in a way that is standards-conforming would be to do a `find` followed by, conditionally, an `insert` or `emplace`.

Comment: `both the insertion and construction should only happen if there is no matching element already in the container`: That's not possible. It needs to create a `T` in order to *find* it. The `T` is constructed either way. So if `T` is move-constructible and you pass a `T&&`, it *must* call the move constructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas good point... by my interpretation the standard is unimplementable. I'll edit the above

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

Of course -when dealing with philosophy- anything can be questioned, but the compiler must do somehow.

The choice of the designers was that -to perform a *move*- there must be a place to *go*.
If there is no such a place, the move doesn't happen.

Note that whatever function takes a &&, it assume the the parameter is "temporary": if it doesn't "stole" the data, the temporary will be destroyed at the expression end.
If the temporariness had been *coerced* (via std::move), the object will stay in any case there until destroyed by its own scope. With or without its original data inside.

Comment: You forget that the library could move the argument to a temporary, and then move from the temporary to its final destination. I don't think there is a limit on the number of moves, even though an implementation will probablement seek to avoid them as much as possible for performance reasons.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The point is not "how many steps". The point is that it is not in the purpose of the container to destroy the incoming content.

The choice was (and was not my fun ...) to move the content if there is a place in the container to place it. Otherwise let it leave where it leaves.