# Emplace or merge on std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am trying to implement this emplace or merge

```
template<typename T>
T& EmplaceOrMerge(std::unordered_set<T>& s,
                  T&& t,
                  std::function<void(T&& a, T& b)> merge)
{
    auto it = s.emplace(std::move(t));
    T& u = const_cast<T&>(*it.first);
    if (!it.second)
        merge(std::move(t), u);
    return u;
}
```

The merge function modifies its second argument in a way that preserves its hashed value. I am concerned with the use of `std::move(t)` in the merge case, because the `emplace` may have moved it already. I have read Microsoft's implementation of `unordered_set` and there is a very nice special case for that, `if constexpr (_In_place_key_extractor::_Extractable)`. It recognizes that its argument `std::move(t)` can be hashed directly (and compared with `operator==` directly), without constructing another object `T`, and returns immediately the equivalent value in the `unordered_set` when there is one.

Does this special case occur in all implementations of the standard library ? If not I have undefined behaviour, and I wonder if there is another way to code this `EmplaceOrMerge`.

Comment: This `const_cast<T&>(*it.first);` is very fishy. Modifying set like this is very fishy. `std::move` here is not a problem, since `std::move` doesn't do anything. It just converts type of reference, if `emplace` didn't performed actual move object is still valid and you can try move it again.

Comment: @MarekR `std::move` does not do anything, but `emplace` might. Modifying the contents of a `unordered_set` is fine, as long as the hashed values are preserved (which is written in the question). If the hashed value is not computed in place by emplace, the argument has been moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, libstdc++ does not perform this optimization.

```cpp
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) { std::format_to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout), "A(A&&)\n"); }
    bool operator==(A const&) const = default;
};
template<> struct std::hash<A> { std::size_t operator()(A const&) const { return 0; } };
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<A> s;
    A a;
    std::format_to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout), "{}\n",
        s.emplace(std::move(a)).second);
    std::format_to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout), "{}\n",
        s.emplace(std::move(a)).second);
}
```

This program prints:

```
A(A&&)
true
false
```

under libc++ (and, presumably, under MS-STL), but prints

```
A(A&&)
true
A(A&&)
false
```

under libstdc++.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ebdnsx91z).

---

> I wonder if there is another way to code this `EmplaceOrMerge`.

You can't get around the fact that libstdc++ will only call `Hash` on an already constructed node. If you can't change the data structure (e.g. to a `std::unordered_map` from an extracted key) one option would be to use the [node-handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) interface, which can avoid side effects on failed insertion. Using it may still pay the cost of a move and move-assign back, but hopefully that is relatively cheap:

```cpp
template<class T>
auto try_emplace(std::unordered_set<T>& s, std::type_identity_t<T>&& t) {
    std::unordered_set<T> s2;
    auto nh = s2.extract(s2.insert(std::move(t)).first);
    auto const ins = s.insert(std::move(nh));
    if (not ins.inserted)
        t = std::move(ins.node.value());
    return std::pair(ins.position, ins.inserted);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qofdsE5j6).

And in your case, you can shortcut the move-assign back, so the overhead is only one move (and extra node allocation):

```cpp
template<typename T>
T& EmplaceOrMerge(std::unordered_set<T>& s,
                  T&& t,
                  std::function<void(T&& a, T& b)> merge)
{
    std::unordered_set<T> s2;
    auto nh = s2.extract(s2.insert(std::move(t)).first);
    auto const ins = s.insert(std::move(nh));
    T& u = const_cast<T&>(*ins.position);
    if (not ins.inserted)
        merge(std::move(ins.node.value()), u);
    return u;
}
```

Comment: Thanks then I'll split my class into a key class and value class, and unordered_map. I was reluctant to go that way because it will chanhe many function signatures in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_set` stores unique keys, so before inserting, it checks if the key is already present in the hash table. In case the key is already present, no insertion is made, and therefore the element is not constructed in-place.
In cppreference, the `emplace` member function is described as 'insert a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container'. Below, it is also written 'the element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately'. So, this action could leave the element in an unspecified state, depending on implementation of its move constructor.
The core problem is that you should not using `emplace(Args&&...)` because what I mentioned before and, in particular, it performs an in-place construction while you are simply moving T. You should pass the arguments to `emplace` using a perfect forwarding if you really want to construct in-place the element, and not using a moving.

Since @krisz commented me an interesting answer about the `insert(value_type&&)` member function, that can leave the element in an unspecified state (it does not ensure the move assignment operator or move constructor are called only if the key does not exist and then the insertion must be effectively performed), I advice you to change your code and check if the key already exists before inserting or moving it.

Comment: `t` is *not* an r-value reference, it's a forwarding reference (aka universal reference); the difference is that `T` is a templated type, so `T&&` is forwarding, not r-value reference. The element need not have been constructed in the general case (I *think* it this case it will be, but if the set and the element were templated separately, it could be the object(s) used to construct the element, not a constructed element at all).

Comment: That cppreference page is not that long, so I wonder how you missed this: "The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately."

Comment: I agree that `insert` would be better, but that still doesn't guarantee anything. See [c++ - std::unordered_set<T>::insert(T&&): is argument moved if it exists - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043716/stdunordered-settinsertt-is-argument-moved-if-it-exists)